# Отдает и POST и GET параметры

Tags: php, post, get

Не могу понять, почему данный код отдает и GET и POST одновременно
Код тут не могу почему-то опубликовать. делаю все по инструкции но не дают отправить поэтому код тут 
То есть с post.php?act=a_new_book отправляется POST на post.php
Как победить эту проблему?

Comment: `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RymPXm`

Comment: `GET` запрос вы передаете в `URL` (?act=a_new_book), а `POST` вы передаете из формы, поэтому и одновременно.

Comment: да. как мне сделать, чтобы я на post.php?act=a_new_book мог отправлять POST запросы?

Comment: Вам никто не запрещает на `post.php?act=a_new_book` отправить `POST` запрос, просто сделайте нормальную форму (погуглите как сделать форму).

Comment: Можете показать пример. просто не допру никак

Comment: Я не про форму.

Comment: А что вы хотите? Какой результат. Просто вас сложно понять.

Comment: post.php?act=a_new_book сюда отправить POST запрос и чтобы вывелось, что было отправлено POST'ом
Например со страницы index.php идет запрос на страницу post.php?act=a_new_book с POST параметрами name=1&user=62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> post.php?act=a_new_book сюда отправить POST запрос и чтобы вывелось,
>   что было отправлено POST'ом Например со страницы index.php идет запрос
>   на страницу post.php?act=a_new_book с POST параметрами name=1&user=62

Переделывая ваш пример:

```
<?php
if($_GET['act'] == "add_new_book" ) {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form method="POST" action="">
<input name="name" type="text" value="1" />
<input name="user" type="text" value="62" />
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
if(!empty($_POST)){
    var_dump($_POST);
}
?>
```

Дальше разберетесь сами